# No matching distribution found for pptk in anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, cmake-gui, anaconda3, pptk

I am trying to install pptk in an anaconda environment by

```
pip install pptk
```

But everytime it returns the same error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pptk (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pptk
```

I tried installing from the .whl file that results from building pptk from source following [this](https://heremaps.github.io/pptk/install.html#build-from-source) instruction, but in this case I am stuck with

```
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" <build folder>
```

The cmake error is as following

```
CMake Error: Could not create named generator NMake Makefiles
```

Although I was not succeeded in installing in any of the created anaconda environment, I was able to install pptk in the base. Would be much of help to know what else i can try to install pptk in anaconda environments.

I am using python 3.8, Ubuntu 20.04, and anaconda 3

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

This is because `pptk` has not released a version that is compatible for `python 3.8`, it can currently only support `python 3.7`

Answer (score 0):

pptk has not released a version for python 3.8 yet, you will have to use python 3.7 or wait